# Javascript/CSS Tooltip that you can hover over and click

Tags: javascript, css, tooltip, dojo

I'm looking for a javascript/css tooltip that can do the following:

1. Shows up when you hover over some page element (such as a help icon.)
2. Repositions itself based on the browser window (for example if it's on the far right of the page, it will show itself to the left of the page element, otherwise it'll show to the right of it. That way it won't go off of the page.)
3. You can hover over the tooltip and it won't disappear. This way you can select text or click on a hyperlink within the tooltip.

I'm using dojo but their dijit tooltip seems to be very inflexible, as it can only spawn off of another dijit element, most commonly a dijit button. I'd rather not having to reference a whole other javascript framework like jquery or prototype so hopefully someone has a way to do this using just one basic script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Again, assuming that you don't mind using jQuery (it's awesome!!) I played around with a few tooltips and found this one the best: http://flowplayer.org/tools/tooltip/index.html

Extensible with good documentation. Check out the 'position' config option and see if that does what you need.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, this ended up being the best option. Even better than the position option was the dynamic option, which figures out if it should show the tooltip above or below the element based on the window positioning. I hate having to include jquery when I'm already using dojo but dojo just doesn't cut it in this realm.

Comment: Cool sounds good! Also note, that on the jqueryui page, you can choose to only download only the plugins that are required for the tooltip. Question though: why are you using dojo? Is there something specific it does well, or is it for 'legacy' reasons?

Comment: I like to use JQuery for smaller projects but when I'm developing an entire web application with nothing but javascript, Dojo takes the cake. It allows me to set up html templates with associated "code-behind" javascript files to control the templates. Besides classes it also has namespaces and even inheritance so I can reuse code throughout my application. All in all, it gives more structure than JQuery does. The downsides of course are crappy support and plugins...

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately for you, the tooltip style plugins available for Dojo are nowhere near the other frameworks (namely: jQuery). Because of this, you have three options:

**Reinvent the wheel.** Take what you learned from other tooltip scripts and build your own from scratch. This option takes the longest development time (and in the inevitable maintenance of cross-browser bugs).

**Extend an existing plugin.** You can take a current tooltip plugin for dojo (or perhaps a library agnostic plugin) and extend its functionality by adding your own scripts to it.

**Use jQuery.** This has already been said twice by others, but let me say it again. jQuery has a thriving plugin ecosystem, and if development/maintenance times are truly important to you, then jQuery should definitely be considered.

Comment: it might help if you provided one or two actual facts.  be constructive.

Comment: @peller what exactly did I say that's not factual? The only thing I said that's remotely subjective is that jquery has a bigger plugin community than dojo, and  as a result he would have better luck with jquery tooltip plugins, especially considering the fact that the number 1 dojo tooltip plugin doesn't meet his needs.

Comment: Phrases like "nowhere near" aren't just subjective, they're unsupported

Answer (score 1):

If you do decide to use jQuery, qTip is a nice jQuery plugin that is very configurable and will probably meet your needs. http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/

Comment: This has the ability to keep the tooltip up when you're hovering over it, which is nice, but I don't see a way to use it declaratively within html, which is a big issue. I don't want to have to generate tooltips within javascript code, especially when some of them have a decent amount of html in them.

Answer (score 1):

I have been using several jQuery plugins, including jQuery TOOLS, Beauty Tips and Cluetip. I think all three meet your requirements.

If instead of a black box you want to know what's going on, I recommend this tutorial:

http://www.sohtanaka.com/web-design/simple-tooltip-w-jquery-css/

(and take a look at the comments section)

Answer (score 0):

The [dijit.Tooltip documentation](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dijit/Tooltip.html) gives two simple examples, the first attaching a tooltip to simple DOM nodes seems to meet your needs.  The second happens to wire up the tooltip to another dijit-based widget (a button).  Note that the property connectId takes a dom node reference or string id.  Note that dijit may be used either programmatically or using a markup-based declaration.

Different tooltip implementations may have different functionality.  Among other things, dijit.Tooltip provides ARIA accessibility for screen readers, keyboard access, bidi enablement, and automatic positioning around a node but within the boundaries of the screen.

Comment: Thanks for the response, unfortunately this doesn't meet my needs. The tooltip widget disappears when you hover over it so you cannot click in it.